# React Native ScrollView/ListView RefreshControl intitially ugly on top right

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, scrollview, pull-to-refresh

I'm having a `RefreshControl` attached to a `ScrollView`. It all works as expected but initially (when I didn't start scrolling), there's always showing a `RefreshControl` on the top right. When I start scrolling, it disappears.

Any idea how to get rid of that?

Code is nothing special, if you want, i'll give it here:

```
// ...
export default class SomeList extends React.Component
{
    // ...
    render() {
        return <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <CustomNavbar />
            <ScrollView 
                style={{marginTop: 35}}
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        tintColor={$.config.colors.style}
                        onRefresh={() => this._refreshList()}
                        refreshing={this.state.listRefreshing}
                    />
                }
            >
                {this._renderItems()}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    }
}
```

[image: image of issue]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in react-native which was introduced in version 0.31 or so.
It was fixed in version 0.34.1 (see [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/dcdf16a0fbe8ded9af6ed75ad0c3ec627e56b75a)), so I guess you're using a previous version.

If you do not wish to upgrade, you can temporarily solve it by settings the background color of the refresh control to transparent:
`<RefreshControl style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}/>`